# Are internal pull-up resistors in microcontrollers connected to Vcc internally?

Tags: resistors, avr, pullup

I'm partly on my way into my first project with the ATMega32U4 and Im trying to understand the internal pull-up resistor. After lots of research, Im struggling to find an outright answer to my question but from my reading its been implied that the internal resistors are connected to an internal power rail. Is this correct? And therefore if I just connect a switch to ground and the pin will I be able to detect the button push?

[image]

To make it clearer:

[image: Option 1]
Option 1

[image: Option 2]
Option 2

Comment: Option 1 you short your power supply to ground when you push the button...

Comment: My question is do I need the connection to 3.3V outside the MCU or is that available inside

Comment: I suggest you correct the first picture and add a resistor between 3V3 and A. Then rotate both pictures 180 degrees. Ground is normally at the bottom.

Comment: But A is the MCu pin which has an internal pull-up?

Comment: Yes, and your A is shorted to 3V3 in that picture. Or remove the 3V3 altogether.

Comment: So option 2 is the way to go, thanks :)

Comment: Yes, but drawing your schematics with GND pointing up is just weird.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The internal pull-ups (and pull-downs, if they also exist) are usually relatively *weak* and are made from PMOS (or NMOS) devices. They usually can support something on the order of about \$30\:\mu\text{A}\$.

When you enable one of these, the software action simply applies an appropriate gate voltage to the device so that it allows a small current to flow. For a pull-up, one side of the device is tied to the \$V_{CC}\$ you also provide via a separate pin to the device. For a pull-down (if available), one side of the device is tied to the ground you also provide via a separate pin. Either way, the other side of the device is tied to the I/O pin.

You can use the internal pull-up to provide a weak current source for use with an external switch. So it is possible (and not infrequently done) to use it with an external switch without having to add an external resistor.

However, this internal pull-up is usually weaker than an externally added resistor (\$\approx 100\:\text{k}\Omega\$ for the internal pull-up versus a not-uncommon \$10\:\text{k}\Omega\$ used when adding an external resistor.) For a simple push-button that is kept close to the MCU, it may not matter so much. But if the switch is placed far away or is used within a rather noisy environment, you could be in trouble using the internal pull-up. Also, if you use the I/O pin for both IN and OUT (muxing it for some reason) then again there may be a reason for something placed externally, instead.

In your case, with an internal pull-up, you can simply hook one side of the switch to the I/O pin and the other side to ground.

Answer (score -2):

> And therefore if I just connect a switch to ground and the pin will I be able to detect the button push?

The theory is correct and works usually in "clean" conditions.

But it will likely fail in the field, because the internal pullups can be relatively high and the switched line works as an antenna. Thus in conditions with external EM (e.g. mains cable close by) you can get fake key presses.

That is why one should always use external resistors (1-10k) instead of the internal (50k-100k Ohms).

Comment: It's not true that it is likely to fail in the field, nor that applications typically require a lower resistance to prevent disturbances and false readings from external EM. Lots of circuits use on-chip pull-ups for these functions with no problems, it's a perfectly common application. I've never had a problem with this on mass-produced equipment. And software debouncing of the input will reduce these rare situations further. I do agree that it's a consideration in certain high EM situations but don't agree that all circuits are prone as you describe. Downvoting until rephrased, I'm afraid.

Comment: Note that there are some µC with pullups in the 10k Ohms rage instead >50k. The trace/wire length is also important - right next to the MCU you probably won't have many problems.